# How to set systemNavigationBarColor to transparent

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we set the bottom system bar to transparent?
I tried:

```dart
SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent)
```

but it seems it's not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `statusBarColor` is set as transparent, it will take on the color of the `AppBar`.

However, if `systemNavigationBarColor` is set as transparent, it will not adopt the color of the bottom navigation bar.

If you want system navigation bar color to be the same as bottom navigation bar color, you will have to specify the required color directly instead of setting it as transparent.

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.bottomNavBarColor)
```

Comment: But whe bottomNavBarColor could change in the app. And maybe could be no Bottom Nav Bar. Open Facebook App for example